# How choose between Clean Arch and Hexagonal Arch(Ports And Adapters)?

Tags: architectural-patterns, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I'm studying architecture patterns and I don't understand which type of scenario is more preferable to use clean architecture or hexagonal architecture. Is there something like that? For example, "If my application has a lot of business logic, is it better to use clean architecture than hexagonal architecture" or is there nothing like that?

Comment: Your second question in this post was encouraging close votes and downvotes for a few different reasons (for example,  for asking  a second questions in the same post which might be answered independently from the first one, but also for not explaining what BFF is, or the misguided idea of applying patterns without knowing the real problem). I took the freedom to remove it. If you want still to ask it, please try to rework it heavily and then ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

> How choose between Clean Architecture and Hexagonal Architecture

You don't.

There is nothing like *"The Clean Architecture"*. This is an **umbrella term** for a few other architectural ideas, including Hexagonal Architecture. See  Bob Martin's blog about the ["Clean Architecture"](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) for more information. So when you design some Hexagonal Architecture, it will also be part of the family of Clean Architectures.